How to unzip large zip file from blob without copying entire content to memory?
I use below code to unzip the large zip file from azure storage blob:
using var sourceFileStram = await blobClient.OpenReadAync();
using (ZipArchive zipArchive = new ZipArchive(sourceFileStream, ZipArchiveMode.Read))
{
     foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in zipArchive.Entries)
     {
        var destinationFilePath = $@"c:\temp\Unzipfiles-zip\{entry.FullName}";
        using (Stream entryStream = entry.Open())
        using (FileStream targetFileStram = new FileStream(destinationFilePath, FileMode.Create))
         {
            await entryStream.CopyToAsync(targetFileStram).ConfigureAwait(false);
         }
     }
 }

The problem is, when calling new ZipArchive(sourceFileStram), seems it need copies the entire stream to memory which cause exception when the file is large, e.g, 4G size.
Is there a way to unzip large file from blob without copying entire blob stream to memory?

Known issue with non-seekable streams https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/59027 there is currently no good workaround. Write the whole thing to a read/write FileStream, seek to the beginning and open the zip off that.

@Charlieface I mean... we could try to figure out a good-ish workaround :P
